# Does the caster of an enchantment spell always know if the spell worked or failed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Reading the story feat [Twisted Love](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/twisted-love-story/) made me think about this, because it say:

> You retain your +2 bonus on saving throws against enchantment effects.
>   If you succeed at a Will save against such an effect, the caster does
>   not learn that you succeeded at your saving throw (effects such as
>   detect magic and analyze dweomer still work normally).

For me this implies that a caster of an enchantment spell knows when her spell failed to work on a target, but I do not remember seeing this anywhere else in the rules (and in my games, it was usually used as a house rule for some spells like [Zone of Truth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/z/zone-of-truth/)). So my question; does the caster of an enchantment spell always know if the spell worked or failed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes and No**, the caster knows whether the spell has succeeded, as long as the spell isn't an area of effect spell.

So the caster can *sense* whether the target succeeded a save against a [Charm Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person/) spell, but not when using a [Zone of Truth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/z/zone-of-truth/) spell

[PRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Saving-Throw): (emphasis mine)

> Succeeding on a Saving Throw
>
> A creature that successfully saves against a spell that has no obvious physical effects feels a hostile force or a tingle, but cannot deduce the exact nature of the attack. **Likewise, if a creature’s saving throw succeeds against a targeted spell, you sense that the spell has failed. You do not sense when creatures succeed on saves against effect and area spells.**

Answer (score 6):

## If a creature succeeds on a saving throw against a [targeted](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) spell, the spell's caster only knows that the spell failed

I admit, that knowing *only* this is a lot like knowing if a creature that's the target of a spell fails *or* succeeds on the saving throw, but there are some weird wrinkles.

Magic on [Saving Throws](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Saving-Throw) on Succeeding on a Saving Throw says that "if a creature’s saving throw succeeds against a targeted spell, [the spell's caster] sense[s] that the spell has failed[, but the caster does] not sense when creatures succeed on saves against effect and area spells." (That's for *any* spell with a [*Target*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) entry that includes creatures, by the way, not *only* spells (and, by extension, many effects) of the school of [enchantment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Enchantment).)

*But* this *is* terrible phrasing, and, I suspect, rarely used as written. For example, when a caster casts [*charm person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person) and the targeted creature *fails* the saving throw, the GM says, "You sense nothing," but if the targeted creature *succeeds* on the saving throw, the GM says, "You sense your spell has failed."

So while a caster knows when creatures targeted by the his spells fail or succeed on their saving throws, that information is delivered *in the most awkward way possible.* It makes casting a targeted spell that has a saving throw like entering a sweepstakes that says *Mail this entry form and, if you don't receive a reply in three days, you've won $1,000!* or like a doctor saying, "If I don't call you in 24 hours, it's not fatal." In short, when a caster casts a targeted spell that has a saving throw, sensing *nothing* about the spell is the *good* result!

However, it appears the designer of the story feat [Twisted Love](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/twisted-love-story/) uses this rule like I suspect most use this rule. The feat's completion benefit says, in part, that "if [the creature possessing the feat] succeed[s] at a Will save against… an [enchantment] effect, the caster does not learn that you succeeded at your saving throw." So it seems to me that the idea is that when a creature that possesses this completion benefit *succeeds* on a saving throw against a targeted enchantment effect, the benefit is *supposed* to change what the caster learns from *The spell failed* to *nothing*. However,— technically,—normally a caster *already* learns *nothing* about the subject's *saving throw* and, instead, learns only if the *targeted spell* has failed, making a strict reading of that part of the Twisted Love feat's completion benefit itself do nothing.

Of course, were a GM actually to *make* such an twisted, highly technical argument—when what the feat's completion benefit is *supposed* to do is *incredibly obvious*—*solely* to deny my PC that completion benefit of the feat Twisted Love, I'd leave that table, and so should you.

---

***Note:*** The [discern lies](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/discern-lies/) *spell does provide the caster with spell failure feedback as described above as it's a targeted spell, but the spell* [zone of truth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/z/zone-of-truth) *normally does* not *provide the caster with such feedback as the spell's an [area spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell). This means when a* zone of truth *spell is hitched to a* [hallow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hallow/) *or* [unhallow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/u/unhallow) *spell—depending on the* zone *spell's caster—none, some, or all of the creatures that enter such a* hallow *or* unhallow *spell's effect may be affected the attached* zone of truth *spell. Hilarity, I'm sure, ensues.*